# How can I debug a ServiceStack service method?

Tags: c#, servicestack

I am using the JsonServiceClient to test a self-hosted service to the database.  The client is receiving an empty array without the 8 records that are in the database.  My problem is that if I put a breakpoint in the Get method of the service, it never fires.

Here is the code for the get method:

```
    public PracticesResponse Get(PracticesGetRequest request)
    {
        var parm = Request.QueryString.Get("source");
        var source = Uri.UnescapeDataString(parm);

        var response = new PracticesResponse
        {
            Practices = Repo.GetBySource(source).ToArray()
        };
        return response;
    }
```

If I put a breakpoint anywhere in the code, it never fires, so I can't tell whether my query parameter isn't being processed correctly, or my repository isn't getting wired up, or what.
If I break execution on the line of code that calls the JsonServiceClient get method and attempt to step into it here:

```
var dto = Client.Get<PracticesResponse>("/practices?source=Desire%20%Map");
Assert.That(dto.Practices.Length > 7);
```

the debugger processes the call without stepping in and the next break is on the Assert.

Here is a link to [simple Visual Studio application](https://github.com/pthalacker/ServiceStackSelfHost.git) that exhibits exactly the same behavior when I try to step into the JsonClient.Get method.

How can I get inside this method to see what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

If the breakpoint never gets hit in debug mode than either the code you think is getting fired is not being executed or the VS.NET debugger is not properly hooked up. But this is normally only an issue in ASP.NET applications where you need to restart the AppDomain by "touching" and resaving the **Web.config** or can also be that the source code is out-of-sync with what's being debugged (normally an issue with trying to debug compiled .dlls with out-of-sync .pdb's).

Since this is a self-hosted my guess is that the code is just not getting hit. Can you expand your question to provide the full Request DTO with any custom routes defined, the code you're using to call the Service as well as the raw HTTP Request / Response (which you can get with Fiddler) which will show what's happening underneath. Also double-check to make sure that your Service is inheriting the `Service` class or implements `IService`.

On Service design I would rename the Request DTO into something more readable like `GetPractices` and instead of manually fetching the parameter from the QueryString to just read it from the Request DTO, also if you're only going to specify the return type in one place it's better that it's annotated on the Request DTO that way the return type information is also available on the client, e.g:

```
PracticesResponse response = client.Get(new GetPractices { Source = src });
```

And I would re-write the Server to something like:

```
public class GetPractices : IReturn<PracticesResponse> 
{
    public string Source { get; set; }
}

public object Get(GetPractices request)
{
    return new PracticesResponse {
        Practices = Repo.GetBySource(request.Source)
    };
}
```

Comment: I have another self-hosted application set up exactly the same way.  It is working and returns the correct data from the database.  When I put a breakpoint in its "Get" method, the breakpoint never fires there either

Comment: I know the code is getting hit because the return value is the PracticesResponse object with an instantiated Practices property.  The only place those objects are created is in the Get method.

Comment: @pthalacker I've not known debugging a self-hosted Console App VS.NET project not to work. I'm assuming you're trying to debug the **Debug** build of a VS.NET project? Does it work when you put a breakpoint at the very start of the Application, e.g. first line in `static void Main(string[] args)`?

Comment: @ mythz I am not sure what you are getting at.  Yes, it breaks on static void Main.  But that just leaves it in the wait state.  There is no way to access the http call from Main.  It also breaks on var dto = Client.Get, but when I step into the Get method, it doesn't break in the Get method on the service.  It never steps into the service. It steps over it and breaks on the Assert.

Comment: @pthalacker Not getting at anything, just checking to see if your debugger is completely broken or not. Don't know why it doesn't let you add a breakpoint in your Service (can you add a breakpoint on any Service?) - never happens to me when debugging a self-hosting app.

Comment: @pthalacker, are you sure the client is configured to use your local service stack url?? This sounds like the url is set to use an IIS hosted service instead of the one running on your local machine, hence why you're breakpoint would never get hit but data is still returned.

Comment: @mythz I have added a link to a VS project to the question.  When I run it, I get the same behavior.  I cannot step into the JsonClient.Get method.

Comment: @CSharper The JsonClient is instantiated using localhost:8090 which is the port on which the self-host is running.  IIS is not running.